# Is an Inbound Change Set automatically deployed if it contains just tests

Tags: deployment, change-set

I deployed a Change Set containing a single test from a sandbox to production. I received an email that states the Change Set has been successfully uploaded.

When I inspect Inbound Change Sets page on the production, the just-uploaded Change Set is not available.

Are Inbound Change Sets containing just tests automatically deployed?

Comment: No, change sets must always be "manually deployed" no matter what the content.

Comment: It happened to me too when I tried to deploy a changeset to a production org. I waited for a long time but it didn't show up in the list. So, I created a **clone** of my existing changeset and pushed it again to the prod org. It showed up in the list within minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, inbound change sets aren't automatically deployed, however, you might see the "change set is not available" message when you try to open the change set immediately after being uploaded to your production org. Try again in a few minutes.

And a change set will only be successfully deployed when you click the "Deploy" button, all the tests succeed in your change set, and you have over 75% code coverage.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it takes from few minutes to hours for the inbound changeset to even showup in the destination org. This is quite normal. And after a changeset is deployed it will appear under "Deployed Change Sets" section. So you can cross check there.

Comment: It's not there. I'll wait for a few hours then.